What should I do to fix a gradle sync issue when I open a new project in Android Studio?
A photo of the issue I am facing, it might help clarify
So I recently decided to resume app development and wanted to create a project with Android Studio. I had to redownload Android Studio and I created a new project. But it is telling me there is a massive Gradle error and no functionalities are working. Originally when I opened Android Studio there was no SDK so I had to download one, then I had to download a JDK. Even after resolving both those, invalidating caches, restarting, and trying again, I'm still getting this error.
I suspect it might be because my grade wrappers and files are misplaced in my directory or in the wrong folder. Is there a way for me to redownload or reinstall gradle specifically to fix this project?
Thanks so much!

Good afternoon, please add Android Studio software to Folder Shield's trusted programs list. And try again. Greetings
